# Delete all non-current branches using Android repo

Tags: android, branch, repo

I apologize if some of my terminology is off, feel free to correct that as well.

If you use `repo sync -c`, you will only download the current branch for every project in the selected manifest. If you don't use `-c` you will download other branches for all projects. Is there a way to delete all other branches after you have already `repo sync`ed without `-c`? I was hoping for something like:

`repo forall -c git [delete all branches except current]`,

but there doesn't seem to be a command like that in git. Can repo do this?